# Nothing happens when I enter 2nd digit of 2nd numbers. What is wrong with the code?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

```
DATA SEGMENT
MSG1 DB 10,13,"ENTER THE FIRST NUMBER: $"
MSG2 DB 10,13,"ENTER THE SECOND NUMBER: $"
MSG3 DB 10,13,"ANSWER: $"
ENDS

CODE SEGMENT
ASSUME DS:DATA,CS:CODE

START:
MOV AX,DATA
MOV DS,AX

LEA DX,MSG1
MOV AH,09H
INT 21H

MOV AH,01H
INT 21H
CALL INPUT8

MOV CL,AL
ROL CL,04H

MOV AH,01H
INT 21H
CALL INPUT8

ADD CL,AL

LEA DX,MSG2
MOV AH,09H
INT 21H

MOV AH,01H
INT 21H
CALL INPUT8

MOV BL,AL
ROL BL,04H

MOV AH,01H
INT 21H
CALL INPUT8
ADD BL,AL

ADD CL,BL

MOV BL,CL
ROL CL,04H
AND CL,0FH

LEA DX,MSG3
MOV AH,09
INT 21H

CALL OUTPUT8

MOV CL,BL
AND CL,0FH
CALL OUTPUT8



INPUT8 PROC

SUB AL,30H
RET
ENDP

OUTPUT8 PROC

ADD CL,30H
MOV DL,CL
MOV AH,02
INT 21H

RET
ENDP

MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H

ENDS
END START
```

Output in command prompt:

[image: Output in command prompt]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you tried debugging?

Comment: I think there is the `H` missing in line `MOV AH,09`

Comment: I see tasm and tlink ... Borland also produced "Turbo Debugger", try it (if you did buy tasm, you probably did buy td as well, if you didn't buy it, then maybe you should consider stop stealing SW, there're many free replacements for assembler (nasm for example) .. unfortunately not so many [easy] for debugger), maybe it will work in your OS directly. If not, try dosbox. Coding anything in ASM without debugger is like assembling a robot blindfolded.

Comment: Perhaps you should take heart at the warning message issued by TLINK. A stack overflow might abruptly terminate your program.

Comment: @jboockmann __09__ or __09H__ represent the same number.

Comment: IDK what's wrong with the code, but [mcve] and [ask]  will tell you what's wrong with the question.  i.e. you didn't even say what you want the code to do, and there are zero comments.

Comment: Look like you are converting the numbers to hex, not dec, is that ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You capture the characters from keyboard and convert them into **hex numbers** in `BL` and `CL`, this happens because you use the higher 4 bits of BL to hold one digit and the lower 4 bits to hold the second digit, with decimal numbers this techinque would not work. Then you execute an addition, but, both numbers are **hex** so the result could contain letters (A..F). In that case, the procedure `OUTPUT8` needs to check if the number in `CL` is a digit (0..9) or a letter (A..F). Also the interrupt to finish the program was not at the right place. Here are both fixes:

```
DATA SEGMENT
MSG1 DB 10,13,"ENTER THE FIRST NUMBER: $"
MSG2 DB 10,13,"ENTER THE SECOND NUMBER: $"
MSG3 DB 10,13,"ANSWER: $"
ENDS

CODE SEGMENT
ASSUME DS:DATA,CS:CODE

START:
MOV AX,DATA
MOV DS,AX

LEA DX,MSG1
MOV AH,09H
INT 21H

MOV AH,01H
INT 21H
CALL INPUT8

MOV CL,AL
ROL CL,04H

MOV AH,01H
INT 21H
CALL INPUT8

ADD CL,AL

LEA DX,MSG2
MOV AH,09H
INT 21H

MOV AH,01H
INT 21H
CALL INPUT8

MOV BL,AL
ROL BL,04H

MOV AH,01H
INT 21H
CALL INPUT8
ADD BL,AL

ADD CL,BL

MOV BL,CL
ROL CL,04H
AND CL,0FH

LEA DX,MSG3
MOV AH,09
INT 21H

CALL OUTPUT8

MOV CL,BL
AND CL,0FH
CALL OUTPUT8

MOV AH,4CH             ;◄■■ THIS CODE COMES FROM
INT 21H                ;◄■■ 26 LINES BELOW.

INPUT8 PROC

SUB AL,30H
RET
ENDP

OUTPUT8 PROC
cmp cl,9                    ;◄■■ IF CL <= 9
jbe digit                   ;◄■■ JUMP TO "DIGIT".
                            ;◄■■ NO JUMP IF CL > 9.
;IF NUMBER IS LETTER (A..F). ◄■■
add cl, 57h                 ;◄■■ CONVERT 10..15 TO 'A'..'F'.
jmp output8display          ;◄■■ SKIP THE "DIGIT" BLOCK.

;IF NUMBER IS DIGIT (0..9). ;◄■■
digit:                      ;◄■■
ADD CL,30H

output8display:             ;◄■■ DISPLAY CL (DIGIT OR LETTER).
MOV DL,CL
MOV AH,02
INT 21H
output8end:
RET
ENDP

;MOV AH,4CH             ;◄■■ THIS CODE SHOULD
;INT 21H                ;◄■■ BE 26 LINES ABOVE.

ENDS
END START
```